# Spreading distinct list columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I have this kind of data:

```
library(tidyverse)
yelp_tbl %>%
select(business_id, categories) 

A tibble: 11 x 2
   business_id            categories
   <chr>                  <list>    
 1 5-1qDFGHvYjBjBYe0B5oiQ <chr [3]> 
 2 isl95tLwXQHlkm_vR0PTqw <chr [6]> 
 3 lNwReGEso2mMhzCr0TM-mw <chr [3]> 
 4 XOvQUSHUjE0KkUuwDUR5OA <chr [1]> 
 5 8Y5p2IQMLX6QjGPzxanexg <chr [4]> 
 6 jozuj1ySOk7DPs7OJloj3A <NULL>    
 7 _TGcRp4wyVbvvDsEHXf0Zw <chr [2]> 
 8 3Mwko7AsZaydBm6d4tWMhg <chr [3]> 
 9 uhdbvZ-yCIl_Yj_sU1OhRg <chr [4]> 
10 ht9AOnxm0IfSoUDJTatS1g <chr [3]> 
11 5P7zzVhWvO8nXGPdy7xqhw <chr [5]>
```

Each business can belong to different categories. So each business could have different values regarding the variable values and the number of variables.

I want to use `spread` to make columns out of the variables values and `fill` "True" or "False" regarding the values of `categories`.

The code which I created so far looks like this:

```
yelp_tbl %>%
  select(business_id, categories) %>%
  mutate(dummy = "True") %>%
  map(unlist) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  spread(categories, dummy, fill = "False")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 26
```

I understand it´s meaning but I don´t know how to fix it in this case.

```
structure(list(business_id = c("5-1qDFGHvYjBjBYe0B5oiQ", "isl95tLwXQHlkm_vR0PTqw", 
"lNwReGEso2mMhzCr0TM-mw", "XOvQUSHUjE0KkUuwDUR5OA", "8Y5p2IQMLX6QjGPzxanexg", 
"jozuj1ySOk7DPs7OJloj3A", "_TGcRp4wyVbvvDsEHXf0Zw", "3Mwko7AsZaydBm6d4tWMhg", 
"uhdbvZ-yCIl_Yj_sU1OhRg", "ht9AOnxm0IfSoUDJTatS1g", "5P7zzVhWvO8nXGPdy7xqhw"
), categories = list(c("Dry Cleaning & Laundry", "Local Services", 
"Sewing & Alterations"), c("Beauty & Spas", "Skin Care", "Medical Spas", 
"Hair Removal", "Health & Medical", "Laser Hair Removal"), c("Food", 
"Grocery", "Specialty Food"), "Restaurants", c("Japanese", "Restaurants", 
"Korean", "Sushi Bars"), NULL, c("Financial Services", "Banks & Credit Unions"
), c("Nightlife", "Dance Clubs", "Bars"), c("Gyms", "Active Life", 
"Trainers", "Fitness & Instruction"), c("Event Planning & Services", 
"Hotels", "Hotels & Travel"), c("Donuts", "Breakfast & Brunch", 
"Restaurants", "Food", "Coffee & Tea"))), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you require leaving the data nested?

Comment: No, but every `business_id` may occur only once i.e. the number of rows must remain.

Comment: In short, do away with the mapping completely and simply spread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use:

To do away with nesting:

**Edit:** Change `NULL` to `False` first.

```
  df$categories[sapply(df$categories,is.null)]<-"False"
df %>% 
  select(business_id, categories) %>%
  head(5) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(categories) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = "True") %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  tidyr::spread(categories, dummy, fill = "False")
```

Otherwsie,

```
library(dplyr)
    df %>% 
     select(business_id, categories) %>%
      head(5) %>%
      mutate(dummy = "True",New=purrr::map(categories,unlist)) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>%
      mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
      tidyr::spread(categories, dummy, fill = "False")
```

Comment: I tried it this way but I got `Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [x]`. Probably you used another sequence in the code then I was using. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the `dput`. In some rows there is a `<NULL>` value. I think this was the reason the code was not working. I got this error when I was using the code on the complete data set. So, it was the same as yours.

Comment: Is the NULL required in the analysis?

Comment: If there is a `<NULL>` value there must be "False" in every cell of the respective row (except the `business_id` of course).